# Data is only getting deleted after refresh and not in real time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a project in which when the user clicks a remove button, a specific item gets deleted. But whenever the user clicks the remove button, the particular array does get deleted in the localStorage, but not in the rendered part, I need to refresh the website so that the changes are applied.

But I want the item to get deleted in real time. Is there anything I'm not doing right in the code?

In the `removeBooks()` function is the one used to delete items. The logic I follow is getting the books localStorage and then looping through all of the items, deleting the one that it is selected. THis is performed correctly, but it doesn't get deleted in real time. I need to refresh the page. I think the last line of this function `localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(myLibrary))` did this correctly but it seems that it doesn't set the data in real time. Is that right?

```
let myLibrary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books')) || [];
// We push the values to our array and printed. If there is nothing, we print an empty array, otherwise we get our localStorge data.

const addBook = (event) => {
// We create the fields so that we can fill our array.
    var fields = {
      title: document.getElementById("title").value,
      author: document.getElementById("author").value,
      pages: document.getElementById("pages").value,
      checkbox: document.getElementById("checkbox").checked
    };


myLibrary.push(fields)

renderBooks()

}


function renderBooks() {

localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(myLibrary))
myLibrary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))

//We map through the array and print the necessary data to our HTML so that the client can see it.

document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = myLibrary.map(item => {
  return `<div>
    <div>Title: ${item.title}</div>
    <div>Author: ${item.author}</div>
    <div>Pages: ${item.pages}</div>
    <div>${item.checkbox === true ? "Read" : "Not Read"}</div>
    <button onclick="removeBooks()">Remove</button>
  </div>`


}).join('')

// If there is no form, we want to display it, otherwise we just don't have the form displayed.
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}

}

// Here I want to make the remove function, the data gets deleted, but not in real time. I need to refresh the page. 
function removeBooks() {
  myLibrary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))
  for (var index = 0; index < myLibrary.length; index++) {
  myLibrary.splice(index, 1);
}
localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(myLibrary))


}

renderBooks()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src=
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js">
 </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="renderBooks()">New Book</button>

  <br><br>
  <div id="demo">
    <table width="230px" align="center" style="box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 100);">
      <tr>
        <td>
           <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input name="title" id="title"/>
          <a href="#" class="close-classic"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="title">Author</label>
          <input name="author" id="author"/>
          <a href="#" class="close-classic"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="title">Pages</label>
          <input name="pages" id="pages"/>
            <label for="title">Read</label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
          <a href="#" class="close-classic"></a>
          <button onclick="addBook(event)">Submit</button>
          <button onclick="renderBooks()">close</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
<div id="bookList"></div>
  <script src="../JS/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding a call to `renderBooks` at the end of the `removeBooks` function. If you feel that's inefficient, do the DOM manipulation more precisely. But the problem you have id that you're updating the datbase but not updating the DOM in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `renderBooks()` to rerender your list after removing an item.

It may help to format your code so that you can see where contexts begin and end.

```js
function removeBooks() {
  myLibrary = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
  for (var index = 0; index < myLibrary.length; index++) {
    myLibrary.splice(index, 1);
  }
  localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(myLibrary));
  renderBooks(); // rerender after updating the list
}
```